# How to create a locator through Open Street Map Data

Tags: arcmap, openstreetmap, geocoding

I need to make a locator for UK addresses and I know Open Street Map has very good data for the UK, I was wondering how I can convert the data for house addresses, which is in xml form, into a locator in Arcmap.

Comment: Do you have the ArcGIS interoperability extension? you will need the osm data in geodatabase format to create a locator http://communityhub.esriuk.com/technicalsupport/2014/9/12/how-to-use-openstreetmap-data-osmpbf-in-arcmap-using-data-in.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to create is working with [Geocoding](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002500000001000000.htm) in ArcGIS.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSbGIv7Lr9Y) is a video tha you can follow the instructions to do the geocoding in ArcGIS.

But before that you need to parse your XML data to get just the address. You can do it using a [simple code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python) using Python (it's installed by default when you install ArcGIS).

Is that make sense for you?

Comment: @SilviaSnow - check out the [ArcGIS Editor for OSM](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/openstreetmap) can provide an easy way to download the addresses from OSM into a geodatabase format if you don't want to deal with converting the XML yourself.

Comment: Thanks, another question, which address locator style should I use, it seems that there's no style that I can use to geocode UK house addresses